# Microsoft login: Curl, Postman, and Dotnet work but Node (axios) request returns 404

Tags: node.js, authentication, axios, azure-functions, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to access a graph api (specifically [bookings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/bookingbusiness-post-appointments?view=graph-rest-1.0)) that only allows the `Delegated (work or school account)` permission.  We need to be able to allow anonymous users to schedule bookings, so we created a fake microsoft user for our server to interact with their api.

I'm able to successfully authorize my user with Postman, Curl, and Dotnet, but I can't get Axios to work for the life of me, even after generating the code from Postman itself.  I'm using the same exact URL in each method.

Note: my environment variables don't have typos and I'm running the code in Azure Functions.  I know this is a hacky solution, but it seems to be the only way to do it using Microsoft Bookings.

Here's my code:

```js
  let data = new FormData();
  data.append('grant_type', 'password');
  data.append('username', process.env.MICROSOFT_USERNAME);
  data.append('password', process.env.MICROSOFT_PASSWORD);
  data.append('client_id', process.env.MICROSOFT_CLIENT_ID);
  data.append('client_secret', process.env.MICROSOFT_CLIENT_SECRET);
  data.append('resource', 'https://graph.microsoft.com/');
  data.append('scope', 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default');

  const config = {
    method: 'post',
    url: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${process.env.MICROSOFT_TENANT}/oauth2/token`,
    headers:
      data.getHeaders(),
    data: data
  };

  axios(config).then(resp => {
    console.log(resp);
  }).catch(e => {
    console.log(e);
  });
```

Comment: You are saying that getting 404, that is not found , different from 403[unauthorized], the url you are passing to `url` property, double check it.

Comment: this may be a correct Url to try..`https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant>/oauth2/v2.0/token`

Comment: Which type of application you have created in AAD?

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran I'm using the same exact URL in both Postman and Axios.  The same issue happens when I hard code the correct URL in the code.  

I had tried the V2.0 URL as well, but still no luck.  Works in Postman, not in Node.

Comment: @ShivaKeshavVarma I don't have access to the AAD configuration, but my coworker says he created it as an AppService registration.

Comment: Wildly enough the request works in dotnet.  Same exact URL as in Node.

Comment: did you find a solution? I have exactly the same issue.

Comment: Unfortunately no.  We ended up using C# functions instead.